# How to select an interval of DATEs that don't have gaps?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle11g

I have daily dates on each row, with start and end and if they're applicable for this query. I need to return all intervals of days, when there is no gap.

Example table:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| ID | DATE_START          | DATE_END            | STATUS | COMMENT                              |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 1      |                                      |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|  2 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 1      |                                      |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+|
|    |                     |                     |        | <-- did this gap visually, following |
|    |                     |                     |        | <-- dates are more than 1 day off    |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 10 | 2019-02-07 06:00:00 | 2019-02-08 06:00:00 | 1      |                                      |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 11 | 2019-02-08 06:00:00 | 2019-02-09 06:00:00 | 1      |                                      |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 12 | 2019-02-09 06:00:00 | 2019-02-10 06:00:00 | 1      |                                      |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 13 | 2019-02-10 06:00:00 | 2019-02-11 06:00:00 | 0      | <-- gap, as STATUS=0                 |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 14 | 2019-02-11 06:00:00 | 2019-02-12 06:00:00 | 1      |                                      |
|----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

The result table should look like that:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| INTERVAL_START      | INTERVAL_END        | IDS      |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 1,2      |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2019-02-07 06:00:00 | 2019-02-10 06:00:00 | 10,11,12 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2019-02-11 06:00:00 | 2019-02-12 06:00:00 | 14       |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Ok, the selecting if `STATUS<>0` is ok. What I struggle with is, that I have no idea on how I should begin the resursive looking, if the next day is also available, and if so, continue until there is no next day (and also collect the IDs of these days).

As this query will have a massive amount of other data, this isn't a problem at all. I just can't wrap my head around this recursive stuff.

It would be very helpful, if this is as Standard SQL as it can get, as this query might be ported in the future.

EDIT: Oh, as you see timestamps there, `DATE_START` always is the same hour/minute as `DATE_END` from the previous day (if existent).

Comment: This is typically solved using `generate_series()` in Postgres

Comment: Looked it up and seems to be exactly what I need, thanks! Problem is, that the current database is Oracle. Postgres migration is still a WIP.

Comment: A solution for both databases typically involves creating a calendar table with e.g. 100 years worth of dates (which is still a small table) and then joining against that calendar table rather than against the result of `generate_series()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MT0 is correct, though I think the `count ... filter` clause is simpler to read than `sum ... case`:

```
with t as (
  select 1 as id, timestamp '2019-01-01 00:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-02 00:00:00' as date_end, 1 as status union
  select 2 as id, timestamp '2019-01-02 00:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-03 00:00:00' as date_end, 1 as status union
  select 10 as id, timestamp '2019-01-07 06:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-08 06:00:00' as date_end, 1 as status union
  select 11 as id, timestamp '2019-01-08 06:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-09 06:00:00' as date_end, 1 as status union
  select 12 as id, timestamp '2019-01-09 06:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-10 06:00:00' as date_end, 1 as status union
  select 13 as id, timestamp '2019-01-10 06:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-11 06:00:00' as date_end, 0 as status union
  select 14 as id, timestamp '2019-01-11 06:00:00' as date_start, timestamp '2019-01-12 06:00:00' as date_end, 1 as status
), t2 as (
  select t.*, lag(date_end) over (order by date_start) as prev_date_end
  from t
  where status = 1
), t3 as (
  select t2.*, count(1) filter (where date_start is distinct from prev_date_end) over (order by date_start) as g
  from t2
)
select min(date_start), max(date_end), string_agg(cast(id as text),',') from t3
group by g
order by g
```

Works in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with PG 9.6 version.

Comment: [Oracle version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc72435b5aa495d0e9e52030a86d8387) and [PostgreSQL version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3928a56ed6d967cd4c7856c131b1ee69) that apart from the string aggregation functions are the same (since `COUNT( .. ) FILTER ()` does not exist in Oracle).

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked wonderful and also has a very straight synthax.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( ID, DATE_START, DATE_END, STATUS ) AS
  SELECT  1, DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-01-02', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, DATE '2019-01-02', DATE '2019-01-03', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, DATE '2019-01-07' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, DATE '2019-01-08' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, DATE '2019-01-08' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, DATE '2019-01-09' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, DATE '2019-01-09' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, DATE '2019-01-10' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, DATE '2019-01-10' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, DATE '2019-01-11' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, DATE '2019-01-11' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, DATE '2019-01-12' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT MIN( date_start ) AS date_start,
       MAX( date_end   ) AS date_end,
       LISTAGG( id, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY date_start, date_end ) AS ids
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         date_start,
         date_end,
         status,
         SUM( change_group ) OVER ( ORDER BY date_start, date_end )
           AS group_id
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           CASE
           WHEN date_start = LAG( date_end ) OVER ( ORDER BY date_start, date_end )
           AND  1          = LAG( status   ) OVER ( ORDER BY date_start, date_end )
           AND  1          = status
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS change_group
    FROM   test_data t
  )
  WHERE  status = 1
)
GROUP BY group_id
```

**Output**:

```
DATE_START          | DATE_END            | IDS     
:------------------ | :------------------ | :-------
2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-03 00:00:00 | 1,2     
2019-01-07 06:00:00 | 2019-01-10 06:00:00 | 10,11,12
2019-01-11 06:00:00 | 2019-01-12 06:00:00 | 14
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80f9d8b7675b2f8507c7038b756cd936)*

Comment: are you some kind of SQL black belt? Works, even on older versions of Oracle. I wait to accept this answers, because I want to test it on a bigger set of data, and because I still hope there's some kind of standard SQL out there for it :D big thanks!

Comment: @Trollwut . . . This *is* standard SQL, except perhaps for the `LISTAGG()`.  Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MT0 thanks your for your commission, worked wonderfully, too! I chose Tomas answer below, as it's a more straight synthax and doesn't add big case blocks. Helped me a lot!